# ¿Cómo escribir a un archivo desde un io.Reader usando Go?

Tags: go

Tengo un `io.Reader` que represente los contenidos de un archivo, y ya quiero escribirlo al disco.  ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

[ioutil.WriteFile](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#WriteFile) parece una opción buena, pero requiere `[]byte`, no `io.Reader`.  Y yo sé que puedo leer todo los contenidos del `io.Reader` a un `[]byte`, pero el archivo puede ser muy grande. Entonces ¿cómo lo puedo hacer directamente con el `io.Reader`?

Comment: ¿Te refieres a algo como [`Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy)?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo: Parece que puede ser buena opción... Pero así necesito saber como obtener el io.Writer para el archivo nuevo. Esas dos pasos haría una buena respuesta.  Quizás hay otras opciones también.

Answer (score 1):

Ya que tu archivo puede ser muy grande, es recomendable ir leyendo por tokens, de tal forma de usar la menor cantidad de memoria principal.

Para esto utiliza un [`Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) de `bufio`. Este se encarga de leer token a token (donde token puede ser: un byte, una línea, una palabra, etc).

Te dejo un programa que realiza lo deseado:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    entrada, err := os.Open("entrada.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer entrada.Close()

    salida, err := os.Create("datos_cp.txt")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer salida.Close()

    // Creo una instancia de scanner con el archivo que vamos a escribir
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(entrada)

    // Defino el tipo de split que realizaré: en este caso, dividiremos los token por bytes. 
    // Ver:
    //   https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanLines
    //   https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanWords
    //   https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanRunes
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanBytes)

    i := 0
    // Leo el archivo hasta que retorne false `Scan`
    for scanner.Scan() {
        // Escribo al archivo, los bytes leídos
        salida.Write(scanner.Bytes())

        // Esta línea es solamente para demostrar la cantidad de iteraciones realizadas
        fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%d steps", i))
        i ++
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy) para hacer esto.

Para obtener un `io.Writer` solo necesitas crear un archivo nuevo. Esto lo puedes hacer con [`os.Create`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create). Esta función te da un `os.File`, que implementa `io.Writer` y también `io.Reader`.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacerlo más o menos así.

```
entrada, err := os.Open("datos.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

salida, err := os.Create("datos_cp.txt")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

_, err = io.Copy(salida, entrada)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/OrpZysw5hV